# Test what view is rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

According to the code following code ([taken from here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs)):

```
describe WidgetsController do
  describe "index" do
    it "renders the index template" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
      expect(response.body).to eq ""
    end
    it "renders the widgets/index template" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template("widgets/index")
      expect(response.body).to eq ""
    end
  end
end
```

It seems like we can test that a certain view is rendered, without actually rendering the view itself, which is a good unit spec.

However, it doesn't work for me:

```
subject { response }

describe '#create' do
  context 'with valid params' do
    before do
      post :create, asset: { uploaded_file: file }
    end

    it { should have_http_status 302 }
    it { should redirect_to '/' }
    it { should render_template 'home' }

  end
end
```

results in:

```
AssetsController
  #create
    with valid params
      should respond with numeric status code 302
      should redirect to "/"
      should render template matcher "home" (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) AssetsController#create with valid params should render template matcher "home"
     Failure/Error: it { should render_template 'home' }
       expecting <"home"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/controllers/assets_controller.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So how should I go about testing the views without rendering them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing a redirect, not a render (as evidenced by the second `it` block)

In a browser that redirect might well result in the home template, but controller specs deal with a single http request/response at a time (as you point out, we're trying to unit test the controller)

If you want to spec what happens after the browser follows the redirect then you need a request spec.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Testing what view is eventually severed up to the user after a redirect would pull the routes file and another action into the unit spec :)

Comment: Would you say a controller spec only tests the status code, where it redirects to / renders and what instance variables are set?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. You can optionally make it actually do the render but that is less common